# Problem representing form-data and returning array of byte in Springdoc

Tags: spring-mvc, springdoc

I have the following piece of code,

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/create/{userId}", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveFile(
        @Parameter(description = "ID of the user") @PathVariable(value = "userId") final String userId,
        @Parameter(description = "Avatar of the user", content = @Content(mediaType = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)) @RequestParam(value = "avatar", required = true) final MultipartFile file
) {
    ...
}

@GetMapping(value = "/get", produces = MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE)
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "OK", content = {@Content(array = @ArraySchema(schema = @Schema(implementation = Byte.class)))})
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile() {
    ...
}
```

And below are the expected and the actual result.
[image: Expected vs Actual]

How do I achieve the expected result? The expected results are from Springfox.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For file format, the not type byte on the spec.    You should send `type: string, format: binary`.

- https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-request-body/file-upload/

So, your requestBody for the post methods is correct.

To describe the return of  type array of byte on your POST method, you can add the following description:

`@ApiResponse(content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", format = "binary")))`

Comment: I was wondering if we could manage to get the `file` thing under the `avatar`

Answer (score 1):

I was faced the same problem last week. My solution was to replace the return type byte-Array by String via SpringDocUtils:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springdoc.core.SpringDocUtils;

@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration {

    static {
        SpringDocUtils.getConfig()
                        .replaceWithClass(byte[].class, String.class);
    }
}
```

For me the advantage of this approach is that every byte[] will be replaced by a String representation, so no corresponding explicit annotations via `@ApiResponse` are required. But I think this depends on the use case.

Comment: The approach looks good, but I'm afraid you would not want to make the use confuse upon a stream of binary data being shown as `String` class.

Comment: To improve on this approach and convey that it's a base64 string of bytes, you can use `replaceWithSchema(ByteArray.class, new Schema<ByteArray> ().type("string").format("base64"))` instead. Then `swagger-ui` will show the schema as `string($base64)`.